# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, twilio-video

I have spent many hours to solve that error or also see othersites to solve that but no solution found so I need help for solve that error

Screenshort here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbBJ5.jpg

I use https://www.twilio.com/blog/video-chat-react-hooks for create video app becuase of that       above error I have not enter into the room

Here is the code below.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Lobby from "./Lobby";
import Room from "./Room";
const VideoChat = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("");
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const handleUsernameChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleRoomNameChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setRoomName(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = fetch("/video/token", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identity: username,
        room: roomName,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then((res) => res.json());
    setToken(data.token);
  };
  const handleLogout = useCallback((event) => {
    setToken(null);
  }, []);

  let render;
  if (token) {
    render = (
      <Room roomName={roomName} token={token} handleLogout={handleLogout} />
    );
  } else {
    render = (
      <Lobby
        username={username}
        roomName={roomName}
        handleUsernameChange={handleUsernameChange}
        handleRoomNameChange={handleRoomNameChange}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    );
  }

  return render;
};

export default VideoChat;
```

Comment: Sounds like you are not getting JSON back from your response. Look in the network panel what is being returned.

Comment: Your screenshot shows 404.... so means file is not there. So figure out why your path is not correct.

Comment: The problem is very likely on the back-end since the `/video/token` route is not found.

Comment: thanks for the help. it's working now!

Comment: Can you share in an answer what you did to get it to work? It would help other people who may have this problem. (I wrote the blog post, so I am glad it is working for you!)

Comment: Yes, why not! I have reformat the code as @kashyap kaki says and run command npm run dev not npm start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As epascarello pointed out, when you make the request to get the token you are receiving a 404 response.

When you run this application, you need to start both the client side application and the server. To do this you should run

```
npm run dev
```

When you run `npm start` it will only run the React application, the server application won't run and you will get 404 responses when making requests to it. This is all based on my blog post on [creating a React application with a proxy to an Express server](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy) in which you can see the details of how this is set up.